# how to fill GridView dynamically on combobox item select?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, combobox

I am using *Microsoft Visual Studio* for building an ASP.NET Website on .net framework 4.5. I have a SQL Server Database (mdf) file for storing image paths. Now on selecting a category in combobox , i want to dynamically fill the GridView Control with images. How to do that? The Combobox code as follows does not seem to work. 
The ASP Code

```
<cc1:ComboBox OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="ComboBox1" runat="server"></cc1:ComboBox>
<asp:GridView ID="dg1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("Id") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="image">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="I1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' Width="240" Height="80" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <%#Eval("Category")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

The C# code for "*ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged*" event

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(RachanaC.cn);
        cn.Open();

        //View images code

        string ddl = "select * from Images where Category ='" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";

        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(ddl, cn);
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        adp1.Fill(dt2);

        dg1.DataSource = dt2;
        dg1.DataBind();

        cn.Close();
```

The Problem arises that no matter which item i choose in ComboBox, it always passes the first Item in the "ddl" string.

Comment: Where are you binding the combo box with all values ?

Comment: @Partha Its in the Page Load event. ` protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(RachanaC.cn);
        cn.Open();

string s = "select distinct category from images";
        SqlCommand idcmd = new SqlCommand(s, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(idcmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);

        ComboBox1.Items.Clear(); ;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
       
        cn.Close();
 
    }`

Comment: Try putting the entire thing into this. if(!IsPostback){}